# How to trigger an email alert when my app encountering internal errors?

Tags: heroku

I am trying to find a solution to setup a simple error notification system when my heroku app encounters an internal error (e.g 500 internal error).

The purpose is to get alerted by email in real time so that I can quickly fix an issue when needed.

Unfortunately I was looking a solution by checking all the options and parameters in the heroku dashboard but I didn't find anything that could help me.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 3):

The [logging](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/monitoring-apps#logging) tool helps in identification of root cause or narrowing down a fix based on the Heroku app, database logs. You can install a [Heroku add-on](https://elements.heroku.com/addons) and setup a logging tool. Here are few [logging tools](https://elements.heroku.com/addons#logging) in https://elements.heroku.com/addons#logging with different set of features that you can set, integrate as per your use case.

[image]

The logging add-on shall enable you in reaching near to the root cause based on the logs/details gathered, however for error or exception notification, the add-on should have the related notification service that can be integrated with your application or should parse the logfiles to store and track when exceptions happen such that they can be parsed/configured to send emails or other types of notifications. [New Relic](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/newrelic) can be one such thing that can be checked.